# How to get rid of the headers in a ps command in Mac OS X ?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, ps

I use a specific ps command namely

```
ps -p <pid> -o %cpu, %mem
```

which gives me a result like

```
 %CPU %MEM
 15.1 10.0
```

All i want to do is to just print these numbers like 15.1 and 10.0 without the headers. I tried to use the 'cut' . But it seems to work on every line.

i.e

```
echo "$(ps -p 747 -o %cpu,%mem)" | cut -c 1-5
```

gives something like

```
 %CPU
  8.0
```

How to get just the numbers without the headers ?

Comment: Use `sed 1d` instead of `cut`; it deletes the first line (and passes the rest through unchanged).

Comment: `cut` manipulates columns, not lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
ps -p 747 -o %cpu,%mem | awk 'NR>1'
```

Using `sed`:

```
ps -p 747 -o %cpu,%mem | sed 1d
```

Comment: Great! That worked man. I am new to osx . What exactly does NR>1 mean ?

Comment: @Pradep, `NR` is short for number of rows. So, `NR>1` means: if the number of rows are greater than one` ... print

Comment: Why do `sed '1d'` instead of just `tail +2`, and why `echo "$(…)"` instead of just the `…`? And why ask `ps %cpu,%mem` and then awk one of the columns away instead of just `ps %cpu` or `ps %mem`? But, most  of all, why ask `ps` to print headers just to strip them, when you can just ask it to not print them?

Comment: @abarnert: On Mac OS X, the BSD-based `ps` (which is different from the GNU `ps`) does not have a documented mechanism to suppress the header line.  The question of columns is valid.  What's wrong with `sed 1d` compared to `tail +2`; they're approximately equivalent, and `sed 1d` has a longer pedigree than `tail +2` (by many years).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes it does have a mechanism to suppress the header line. See my answer. Also, what's wrong with using complicated/general commands like sed, awk, etc. instead of simple commands like tail is that they don't bring up questions like the OP's "What exactly does NR>1 mean" (which would take him a lot of effort to figure out via the manpage).

Comment: @abarnert: OK - I looked for an option 'suppress header line' and not for 40-odd words ending 'and if the moon is in the right phase and the planets are aligned properly then `ps` will omit the headers'.  My bad!  (Actually, I take that back.  It isn't my bad; that is horribly circuitous and hard to use.  It is ludicrous, in fact.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: How is it hard to use? I do it all the time, and have been doing so for decades. It certainly is hard to _discover_ if you've never run across it before, but that's a general problem with learning via manpages. That's why, ideally, there are HOWTO docs and sites like this one…

Comment: @abarnert, I find using `awk` to print columns strips the leading whitespace from `$1`. It just neatens the output. No harm in teaching a little `awk` is there?

Comment: @steve: No harm, but if someone is trying to, e.g., print the second column out of `ps -o %mem,%cpu`, it's probably better to explain why that's overly complex and wasteful than to give them `|awk '{ print $2 }'` as a new magic invocation to memorize without understanding. And again, why would you teach someone `echo "$(ps -p 1937 -o %cpu,%mem | awk 'NR>1')"` instead of `ps -p 1937 -o %cpu,%mem | awk 'NR>1'` if you're not deliberately trying to mystify?

Comment: @abarnert, I was simply keeping the format the same; never any intent to mystify. I will update my answer for you.

Comment: But the format wasn't the same. The OP is doing `echo "$(…)" | foo`, while you're doing `echo "$(… | foo)"`, which is very different. (Although since they're just different no-ops, it turns out not to matter here.) This is why keeping things simple is important—because even talented and experienced coders (you obviously know your stuff) can and do make transformations like that without realizing it.

Comment: @Steve, *"NR>1 means: if the number of rows are greater than one..."*  This is a test that applies to *each* line, so the translation should really be "If the number of **the row** is greater than one."

Comment: @Wildcard: Yes, the explanation makes little sense if it is not recognised that it is a test performed against each record. The longer explanation should add that `NR` is actually the current _record number_ variable and that the default record separator variable (`RS`) is a newline character.

Comment: Yep.  At first I wrote about **R**ecord number also in my comment, then I decided it didn't matter in this context.  :)

Comment: This comment list has made my top 10! No doubt Pradep has long since retreated to a monastery and abandoned all thought of a career in programming.

Answer (score 31):

The BSD (and more generally POSIX) equivalent of GNU's `ps --no-headers` is a bit annoying, but, from the man page:

> ```
>  -o      Display information associated with the space or comma sepa-
>          rated list of keywords specified.  Multiple keywords may also
>          be given in the form of more than one -o option.  Keywords may
>          be appended with an equals (`=') sign and a string.  This
>          causes the printed header to use the specified string instead
>          of the standard header.  If all keywords have empty header
>          texts, no header line is written.
> ```

So:

```
ps -p 747 -o '%cpu=,%mem='
```

That's it.

If you ever do need the remove the first line from an arbitrary command, tail makes that easy:

```
ps -p 747 -o '%cpu,%mem' | tail +2
```

Or, if you want to be completely portable:

```
ps -p 747 -o '%cpu,%mem' | tail -n +2
```

The `cut` command is sort of the column-based equivalent of the simpler row-based commands `head` and `tail`. (If you really do want to cut columns, it works… but in this case, you probably don't; it's much simpler to pass the `-o` params you want to ps in the first place, than to pass extras and try to snip them out.)

Meanwhile, I'm not sure why you think you need to eval something as the argument to echo, when that has the same effect as running it directly, and just makes things more complicated. For example, the following two lines are equivalent:

```
echo "$(ps -p 747 -o %cpu,%mem)" | cut -c 1-5
ps -p 747 -o %cpu,%mem | cut -c 1-5
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Actually tells you how to do it with `ps`.

Comment: @VivinPaliath: Thanks--but it's certainly at least worth having the other answers. Besides generally providing information that's useful for the OP to learn, some of them give you a solution that will work portably across BSD, GNU, and some legacy userlands, which might be helpful to other searchers.

Comment: that's good point (regarding other *nixes). The other answers are certainly useful; it's just that I prefer answers that tell you how to do it using the tool rather than having to munge output. :)

Comment: @VivinPaliath: Well, obviously I agree (or I wouldn't have written this answer), I just want to make sure nobody downvotes the other useful answers or anything like that.

Comment: On Solaris you have to use more than on `-o` option: `ps -e -o pid= -o ppid= -o args=`

Comment: busybox's implementation of `-o foo=` seems to be broken; it prints an empty line.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`ps --no-headers`](http://ss64.com/bash/ps.html):

> `--no-headers   print no header line at all`

or use:

```
ps | tail -n +2
```

Comment: That might work on Linux; it does not work on Mac OS X which uses a BSD implementation of `ps`, not the GNU version.

Comment: Specified for a Mac. Macs don't take the `--no-header` parameter

Answer (score 4):

Already picked the winner. Drats...

If you're already using the `-o` parameter, you can specify the headings for the particular columns you want to print by putting an equal sign after the name, and the column name. If you put a null string, it'll print no headings:

With standard headings (as you had):

```
$ ps -p $pid -o%cpu,%mem
 %CPU %MEM
  0.0  0.0
```

With custom headings (just to show you how it works):

```
$  ps -p $pid -o%cpu=FOO,%mem=BAR
  FOO  BAR
  0.0  0.0
```

With null headings (Notice it doesn't even print a blank line):

```
$ ps -p $pid -o%cpu="",%mem=""
 0.0   0.0
```

Comment: You don't need the quotes; you can just do `-o%cpu=,%mem=` (as I showed in my answer).

Comment: @abarnert I saw your answer after I did mine. I never tried it without the quotes before, but it does work.

Comment: Yeah, it never hurts to put in the quotes, and if I were improvising at the command line I'd probably add them too… (You'll notice that I have a different set of unnecessary quotes—theoretically, some sh-derived shell might give a special meaning to %cpu, but I don't believe any actual shell treats % specially unless followed by a digit, so I'm just being pointlessly paranoid.) So, that's not a criticism, just a comment that might one day save you a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command and you don't need to add pcpu="", it worked for me:

ps -Ao pcpu=

Answer (score 0):

Use $ps - | grep -v <header_name>